Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge if $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$
I'm given the following problem: Does the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converge if $a_n \geq 0$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$?
(It's a bit unclear to me if "for $n \in \mathbb N$" means for all $n$, or for $n$ after some $N$, I'm assuming the former since it's a stronger condition)
My question: Is this solution correct?
My attempt:
The series can both diverge and converge, because of the following 2 examples
Example for divergence: consider a diverging series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n+1}$, then $a_n = \frac{1}{n+1} \geq 0$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{n+1}}<1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.
Example for convergence: consider $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)^n$, which converges by the root test: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt[n]{\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)^n}=0<1$. and $a_n=\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)^n\geq0$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\sqrt[n]{\Bigl(\frac{1}{n^2}\Bigr)^n}<1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

What question are you asking? There's no question in the post, and you seem to be answering the question in the title.

@GregMartin yes I'm answering the question in the title, I'll put the question in the post as well if that's some code of conduct I wasn't aware of. apologies

Yes, we do prefer the post to ask a question explicitly, good inference. But I'm confused—why are you posting a question when you know the answer? If you want to record this knowledge on the site, I guess putting the answer in an answer to the post is preferable.

@GregMartin I guess solution-verification tag exists for a reason? I make mistakes often so I want to check if it's correct

@powerline read the description of the tag

Ok, so it sounds like the question you're asking is not "does this series converge" but rather "is this solution correct"? That's fine (making it explicit helps), although please read the description of the solution-verification tag for how to pose such a question well.

@SineoftheTime ah I got it, thanks.

Mathematically, it might simplify things to note that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ is exactly the same as the simpler $a_n<1$ in this context.... Also, for a convergent example $\sum 2^{-n}$ is also simpler (not that yours is wrong).

Do you really mean $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$? Because that is equivalent to  $a_n<1$ for $n \in \mathbb N$. Or do you mean something like $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} < 1$?

@MartinR well, I guess it's just $\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$, I quoted the problem exactly as I got it

I'm guessing the question-asker didn't ask their intended question.

As usual in this kind of problem what you want is $0\le\sqrt[n]{a_n}\le c<1$ because you can then compare your series with the geometric one $\sum c^n$.
When you go directly with $0\le\sqrt[n]{a_n}<1$ then the convergence test is inconclusive as you noticed for the harmonic series.
Indeed $\sqrt[n]{\frac 1n}\to 1^-$ and you cannot squeeze a $c$ in between.
Also remember that the first terms of a series do not matter since a finite sum is always convergent, only the tail is important. Therefore the inequality is often worded as true $\forall n\ge n_0$, which even if it seems weaker than for all $n$, is in fact giving more leniency for the first terms (but you do not lose in generality since these terms can be safely ignored anyway).
